# How to clear the back stack (current task) from Acrtivities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I need to run an activity but clear all backstack, even an activity I run a new one.

Here is an example.

```
A->B
```

Activity A starts the Activity B

I have tried to use following flags when starting the Activity B.

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
```

But when the Activity B is started I still can see the Activity A in a task.
Using the following command

```
adb shell dumpsys activity | grep -i run
```

And got the following result

```
Running activities (most recent first):
    Run #0: ActivityRecord{5296b78c u0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher t1}
Running activities (most recent first):
    Run #2: ActivityRecord{528a3310 u0 com.test.app/com.test.app.B t19}
    Run #1: ActivityRecord{52bb7a34 u0 com.test.app/com.test.app.A t19}
    Run #0: ActivityRecord{52c7ed5c u0 com.android.documentsui/.DocumentsActivity t11}
 ACTIVITY MANAGER RUNNING PROCESSES (dumpsys activity processes)
User #0: mState=RUNNING
```

As you can see activity A is still here. Is it possible to clear the back stack ?

Comment: Are you finishing your activity A while moving toward activity B?

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
   startActivity(intent);
   finish();//you want to close your activity,just call finish
```

Comment: are you use finish()?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Here `IntentCompat` the class added in Android Support library.

Answer (score 0):

If pressing Back in Activity B should never navigate back to Activity A you can  set it in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name=".A"
        android:noHistory="true">
</activity>
```